# find all sublist of list in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, list, python-3.x

I need to find maximum length of sublist with first element greater than last.

if a original list has first element greater than last then i just return the length of list. if not i have to find the sublist of list with maximum length and first element greater than last.

I written the coding for finding all sublist and checking condition. My code takes more time for larger list to convert those into sublist. i need to change this code more efficient. I think for method to get the combination of sublist takes more time. anyone can provide me efficient way?

```
from  itertools import combinations

def combos_with_exclusion(lst,length):
    d=0

    for combo in combinations((e for e in lst),length):
        #yield list(combo)
        #print (list(combo))
        sublist=list(combo)
        #print(sublist[0])
        le=len(sublist)
        if(sublist[0]>sublist[le-1]):
            d=len(sublist)
        if(d!=0):
            break
    return d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to compute all the combinations first.

Start with the whole list. Then try all sublists of length "list_length - 1", then all sublists of length "list_length - 2", and so on.

As soon as you get a list that meets the requirement, break out of the loop. No need to try shorter lists.

```
def max_length(input_list):
    input_length = len(input_list)
    for i in range(input_length):
        for j in range(i + 1):
            if input_list[j] > input_list[input_length - i - 1 + j]:
                # return length
                return input_length - i
                # or return sublist, I'm not sure what you want
                return input_list[j: input_length - i + j]

print(max_length([1,5,7,8,9,6,4,2,3,5,7,8,6,2]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pretty straightforward solution. It should be much faster than your solution :

```
l = [1, 21, 34, 55, 2, 12, 43, 54, 43]
n = len(l)
max_len = 1
max_list = l[0]

for i, x in enumerate(l):
    for j in range(i + max_len, n):
        y = l[j]
        if x > y:
            max_len = j - i + 1
            max_list = l[i:j + 1]
print(max_len)
# 6
print(max_list)
# [55, 2, 12, 43, 54, 43]
```

Comment: Searching from longest sublists down allows you to break out of the loop as soon as you find the longest one (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

If I don't misunderstand your meaning,I tried to write some code,it might be helpful:

```
l1=[1,21,34,55,2,12,43,54,43]
l2=list(reversed(l1))

r=[]
for i in l1:
    for j in l2:
        if i>j:
            sublist=l1[l1.index(i):len(l1)-l2.index(j)]
            if sublist:
                r.append(sublist)
            break
print(r)
print(max([len(i) for i in r]))
```

Ouput:

```
[[21, 34, 55, 2, 12], [34, 55, 2, 12], [55, 2, 12, 43, 54, 43], [54, 43]]
6
```

If I missed something,please tell me to improve it.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You van use list comprehensions:

```
l=[1,21,34,55,2,12,43,54,43]

lst = [l[i:e+i+1] for i in range(len(l)) \
        for e, x in enumerate(l[i:]) \
        if x < l[i]]

print(max(lst, key=len))
#[55, 2, 12, 43, 54, 43]
```